# Nodejs TCP server manage errors

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I've a TCP Server running using nodejs on Debian 8.

I am having some issues with TCP port reusing due to the tcp stack of the tcp clients I have (out of my control. they have a static tcp source port).

I want to know which of this error handling is the correct one:

```
net.createServer(function(sock) {
    [...]
    sock.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Network error ' + e);
        sock.destroy()
    })}).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

Or

```
net.createServer(function(sock) {
    [...]
    sock.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Network error ' + e);
    })}).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call `sock.destroy()`, since it's the socket itself that encountered an error situation so it will clean up after itself (you'd call it if something else in your app has caused an error, and you want to close the socket quickly).

However, you're missing another error handler, namely one attached to the server itself. This is the one that will get called with `listen()` fails:

```
net.createServer(function(sock) {

  ...

  sock.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('Socket error:', e);
  });

}).listen(PORT, HOST).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('Server error:', e);
});
```